# How can i reverse lookup an audio codec id? (Codec = 0x3040)

Tags: codec

i have a bunch of audio files with this header:

```
General
Complete name                            : (...)
Format                                   : Wave
File size                                : 2.02 KiB
Duration                                 : 581 ms
Overall bit rate                         : 28.5 kb/s
FileExtension_Invalid                    : act at9 wav

Audio
Format                                   : 3040
Codec ID                                 : 3040
Duration                                 : 581 ms
Bit rate                                 : 27.6 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 1 channel
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Stream size                              : 1.96 KiB (97%)
```

I'm stuck in getting a codec for the 0x3040 id

Might it be a non-public codec developed for just an application?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the answer was: libopus Opus

and can be readed by: https://vgmstream.org/